State Restoration in SwiftUI
I am looking at state restoration in a SwiftUI app. I found this sample code from Apple which uses ObservableObject and stores the navigation data in the SceneStorage whenever the object changes.
I am wondering how to best approach this with an Observable class (the macro from iOS 17). Would I rebuild this by using the .values stream of the needed properties or is there a more clever way. Here is the code snippet I am referring to:
// In Navigation: ObservableObject
var objectWillChangeSequence: AsyncPublisher<Publishers.Buffer<ObservableObjectPublisher>> {
    objectWillChange
        .buffer(size: 1, prefetch: .byRequest, whenFull: .dropOldest)
        .values
}

// In View
.task {
    if let data = data {
        navModel.jsonData = data
    }
    
    for await _ in navModel.objectWillChangeSequence {
        data = navModel.jsonData
    }
}

Given my navigation model has more than one navigation path I could theoretically built a stream using pathOne.values and combineLatest with pathTwo.values but I would like to know if there is a more straightforward way. Of course I know I can theoretically still use an ObservableObject as the example code does but I'd rather use the new Observable macro if this works.

@Observable doesn't work very well with publishers. If you need the buffer operator, you should just keep using ObservableObject. Otherwise, you can conform the @Observable class to Equatable and observe it with onChange.

I don't think that Apple sample has correct source of truth design or even data types eg he says “First, I'll encapsulate my navigation state in a NavigationModel type. That lets me save and restore it as a unit so it's always consistent.” however encapsulating both vars into a custom state struct is the normal way to do this and the usual reason for objects is for asynchronous loading/saving however .task replaces the need for that. Curt has even used customs structs before in his Book club talk so perhaps he doesn’t write the code for his slides. That being said, to convert the model from Combine to Observable with a stream for changes try this:
.task {
    let navModelJsonDataDidChange = AsyncStream {
        await withCheckedContinuation { continuation in
            withObservationTracking { 
                let _ = navModel.jsonData // let _ required to fix compilation error
            } onChange: {
                continuation.resume()
            }
            // return navModel.jsonData // this would insert the new value in the stream but we won't bother because it would make our simple loop more messy.
        }
    }

    var iterator = navModelJsonDataDidChange.makeAsyncIterator()
    repeat
    {
        data = navModel.jsonData
    }
    while await iterator.next() != nil // loops until task is cancelled which causes the stream to return nil.
}

Where navModel is @Observable class stored in an optional @State that is init once, somewhere like onAppear. The repeat/while loop lets us get the initial value and any changes on the same line.
Other options are .task(id:) or simply .onChange. I don't think navModel needs to be a class since it doesn't do anything asynchronous.

Wow withObservationTracking works inside withCheckedContinuation? I thought withObservationTracking only detects changes in the { navModel.jsonData } closure, which does not change anything at all, and so onChange would not be called. Can you explain how this works?

You list the properties you want to track by calling their getters which has long lifetime like an object retained by the stream. When those properties are set by anything else the onChange is called before the value changes. Then the getter after the await inserts the new value into the stream. It’s from here btw https://www.malcolmhall.com/2024/05/04/create-an-asyncstream-from-withobservationtracking-function/

Thanks for the detailed answer. I'll have a close look at this but this is essentially what I was asking for. When stating "other options are task(id:)" you are referring to putting navigationModel.jsonData as the id basically saying to run the task whenever the id(jsonData) changes, right? In this case no asyncstream is needed I guess? This sounds a lot simpler to me if i am understand it correctly

Yes simpler but since there are no awaits, onChange makes more sense. Maybe check what thread the task runs on in Apples sample

A computed binding for the nav path might be a better idea that uses the SceneStorage as the source of truth. You'll see this in the Core Data team's SwiftUI talks.
